# Separate manifest for instant app

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-instant-apps

Can I use different manifests for instant app and a regular application?
In more detail, I need to specify different classes "App" in the `"android:name=App"` field (application tag).

Comment: Do you mean that the app module contains a `android:name=”App”`, which would override a feature module’s `android:name=”AppFeat”` when it is an installed app?

Comment: @TWL Yes, normal application is work, but instant work only debug version(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this:

If you must have two different manifests, then you will need to use `tools:replace`, example:

Your installed-app module’s manifest:

```
<application
    android:name="com.example.App"
    tools:replace="android:name"/>
```

Your feature module’s manifest:

```
<application
    android:name="com.example.feature.AppFeat">
```

When your installed-app is built, it will run with `App`, and when your instant-app is built, it will run with `AppFeat`. You can play with variations of this.

But it would be easier if you use [isInstantApp()](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/instantapps/PackageManagerCompat.html#isInstantApp()) to branch off, in just one Application implementation.

Comment: I have a combination of Kotlin/Dagger2. So, I need to call Android injector from App class for all my activities. I tried tools:replace way, but I still never see my App.onCreate() being called from the debugger. I looked at isInstantApp(), but it looks like meant for use within an Activity. Are you sure that it is called for you?

Comment: Yes, I have tested `InstantApps.isInstantApp()` in an Application implementation. It works for me.

Answer (score -1):

To help you start with, here is a sample code from github about instant apps. You can check the structure of the code below:

```
<!--
  ~ Copyright 2017 Google Inc.
  ~
  ~ Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
  ~ you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
  ~ You may obtain a copy of the License at
  ~
  ~      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
  ~
  ~ Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  ~ distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
  ~ WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
  ~ See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
  ~ limitations under the License.
  -->

<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.google.android.instantapps.samples.hello.feature">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
            android:supportsRtl="true">

        <activity
                android:name=".HelloActivity"
                android:label="@string/title_activity_hello">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter
                    android:autoVerify="true"
                    android:order="1">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                <data android:scheme="https" />
                <data android:scheme="http" />
                <data android:host="hello.instantappsample.com" />
                <data android:pathPrefix="/hello" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data
                    android:name="default-url"
                    android:value="https://hello.instantappsample.com/hello" />
        </activity>
        <activity
                android:name=".GoodbyeActivity"
                android:label="@string/title_activity_goodbye">
            <intent-filter
                    android:autoVerify="true"
                    android:order="2">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                <data android:scheme="https" />
                <data android:scheme="http" />
                <data android:host="hello.instantappsample.com" />
                <data android:pathPrefix="/goodbye" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>
</manifest>
```

Here is the [Manifest file structure](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html#filestruct) to help you further in your build stage.

> The code snippet below shows the general structure of the manifest
>   file and every element that it can contain. Each element, along with
>   all of its attributes, is fully documented in a separate file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<manifest>

    <uses-permission />
    <permission />
    <permission-tree />
    <permission-group />
    <instrumentation />
    <uses-sdk />
    <uses-configuration />  
    <uses-feature />  
    <supports-screens />  
    <compatible-screens />  
    <supports-gl-texture />  

    <application>

        <activity>
            <intent-filter>
                <action />
                <category />
                <data />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data />
        </activity>

        <activity-alias>
            <intent-filter> . . . </intent-filter>
            <meta-data />
        </activity-alias>

        <service>
            <intent-filter> . . . </intent-filter>
            <meta-data/>
        </service>

        <receiver>
            <intent-filter> . . . </intent-filter>
            <meta-data />
        </receiver>

        <provider>
            <grant-uri-permission />
            <meta-data />
            <path-permission />
        </provider>

        <uses-library />

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Thanks, I know about the structure, but this is not the answer to my question.